# Powershell, Excel search for folder

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel List with folder paths in column "A". I would like to check if those paths / folders do exist. If they exist, put "OK" in column "B", if not, put "error" in Column "B".

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your Excel as CSV file

Then in PowerShell do:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\theFile.csv' -Header 'path','exists' -UseCulture
foreach ($item in $csv) {
    $item.exists = if (Test-Path -Path $item.path) {'OK'} else {'error'}
}
# re-save the file
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\theFile.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Finally double click that file to open in Excel